# Only insert if the value doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | gamertag | timestamp |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

So I have the table above I want to only insert a gamertag if it doesn't already exist. How could I do that?

```
$gamertag = "l RaH l";
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gamertags`(`gamertag`)VALUES ('".$gamertag."')");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do both things:  [Create a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on column gamertag **and** use `insert ignore`.

The unique index prevents a duplicate row from being added.

The insert ignore prevents mysql from issuing a warning when the duplicate row is not added.

Comment: @Dan Thanks!  And also for adding the link.

Answer (score 3):

[Index gamertag column as unique](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). Then only thefirst insertion will work. If the same gamertag exists, the `INSERT` will fail.

Comment: you can use unique like @sarwar answer , or use

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE][1] 

so if the key exist only update the timestamp

  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: That assumes the constraint exists in the first place, or you can't use such a query.

Answer (score 2):

you could try `INSERT IGNORE`, check mysql dev pages about this keyword :)

edit - based on the comments below : ya, you need to have gamertag column as a unique index..
and those who upvoted might have taken this for "understood".

edit - updating the answer finalizing the answer :

`$gamertag = "l RaH l";

mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO gamertags(gamertag)VALUES ('".$gamertag."')");`

don't forget to unique index-ify the gamertags column

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` alone will not stop the `INSERT` from creating duplicate rows, which he asked not to do. This doesn't answer the question. Those who upvoted it clearly don't know what they're doing and should not be participating in this question.

Comment: @dan the OP didn't mention anything about stopping the insert.

Comment: Yes he did, that's his whole question. Telling him to just run an INSERT IGNORE query every time just leads to exactly what he asked NOT to do.

Comment: @dan "want to only insert a gamertag if it doesn't already exist." `INSERT IGNORE` will do just that (again assuming there is a unique index in place). I can't find in the question that the insert should fail with a error?

Comment: @everyone I'm really confused.. so what should the query look like? I add the unique to gamertag field..

Comment: @The Scrum Meister if there was a unique index he wouldn't have this question. There isn't a unique index, telling him to create one was the right answer. As his new comment shows...

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, @Dan Grossman : Myself and The Scrum Meister are assuming that unique index is "understood", while Dan is requiring us to drop our assumptions and be specific. I agree and edited the answer, which now answers the question. Can we spare the war now ?

Comment: @dan I missed understood you, i assumed you wrote your original comment after you saw mine.

Comment: @AndrewFerrara : your original code should go like this : `$gamertag = "l RaH l";
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `gamertags`(`gamertag`)VALUES ('".$gamertag."')");`  
don't forget to unique index-ify the gamertags column

Answer (score 0):

Insert or update is not available (at least it was not) for MySQL

Look at these work around for MySQL: http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html

Comment: MySQL has had `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` since version 4.1, which is 7 years old.